# Assign a number to partitions of rows based on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the following table

```
ID, FileSize, PrintGroup
1   100         1
2   300         1
3   500         1
4   600         1
5   700         1
6   100         1
7   200         1
8   300         1
9   200         1
10  200         1
11  300         1
12  400         1
13  100         1
14  300         1
15  200         2
16  300         2
17  400         2
18  100         2
19  300         2
20  200         2
21  300         2
22  400         2
23  100         2
24  300         2
25  200         2
26  300         2
27  400         2
28  100         2
29  300         2
```

I am trying to create a column which contains a number which will be appended to a filename to ensure that a zip file is not over a certain size per print group.
For example:
If my maximum zip size was 1000 in this scenario. ID 1,2,3,6 could be in SplitAllocationNumber 1 and so on as the sum of their FileSize columns is <= 1000

I have tried NTILE however there is no guarantee that the Sum of each groups FileSize would be less than or equal to the max (1000 in this example)
This is the query I have tried so far

```
DECLARE @maximumZipSize INT = 1000;

DECLARE @totalFileSize INT = (
        SELECT SUM(FileSize)
        FROM [PendingDocuments]
        );

DECLARE @ceiling DECIMAL(10,2) = @totalFileSize / CAST(@maximumZipSize AS DECIMAL(10,2));

DECLARE @totalGroups INT = (
        CASE CEILING(@ceiling)
            WHEN 0
                THEN 1
            ELSE CEILING(@ceiling)
            END
        );

SELECT 'Total Groups: ', @totalGroups
UNION
SELECT 'Total File Size: ', @totalFileSize
UNION
SELECT 'Max Zip Size: ', @maximumZipSize
UNION
SELECT 'Ceiling Result:', @ceiling

SELECT 
    p.ID,
    FileSize,
    p.PrintGroup,
    SplitAllocation.Number
FROM PendingDocuments p
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        ID,
        NTILE(@totalGroups) OVER (PARTITION BY PrintGroup ORDER BY ID) AS Number
    FROM PendingDocuments
) AS SplitAllocation
ON p.ID = SplitAllocation.ID
```

How can I ensure each group's Sum of FileSize is <= 1000?

Comment: If the max is 1000, what do you do with the other files? Are they lost? Put in a different archive?

Comment: The groups sum of FileSize can be less than 1000 but never over, so it should be given a new number which would result in the stragglers being put in a smaller zip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this type of problem is inherently iterative. A slight variation -- where you fill the bins to exactly 1000 and split the files at the boundary between two bins -- is not iterative.

So, the only solution that I know uses a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select id, filesize, printgroup, 1 as bin, filesize and binsize
      from t
      where id = 1
      union all
      select id, filesize, printgroup,
             (case when filesize + binsize > @threshold then bin + 1 else bin end) as bin,
             (case when filesize + binsize > @threshold then filesize else fiesize + binsize end) as binsize)
      from cte join
           t
           on t.id = cte.id + 1
     )
select *
from cte;
```

Your question mentions appending the bin onto the filename.  I don't see filename in the question and I assume you can handle whatever subsequent processing is needed once the bin is assigned.

Comment: The filename is going to be hardcoded value. So each zip will be 'PBS_<GroupNumber>.zip'. Can you explain what is going on a little more in the query you have provided please.

Comment: @Emcrank . . . Recursive CTEs are a way to "walk through" data -- more typically used for hierarchical data.  The explanation is a bit long.  You can start with the documentation:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.  However, there might be better explanations on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone wants to know the answer to this, I used a combination of a CTE and a recursive CTE to get the desired result.

```
DECLARE @maxZipSize INT = 1000;

WITH RunningTotal
AS (
    SELECT p.ID,
        PrintGroup,
        SUM(p.FileSize) OVER (
            ORDER BY p.ID
            ) AS CumlativeFileSize,
        fileSizes.FileSize
    FROM PendingDocuments p
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT ID,
            FileSize
        FROM PendingDocuments
        ) AS fileSizes
        ON fileSizes.ID = p.ID
    ),
recursiveCTE
AS (
    SELECT RunningTotal.ID,
        RunningTotal.CumlativeFileSize,
        RunningTotal.FileSize,
        RunningTotal.FileSize AS BinSize,
        1 AS BatchNumber
    FROM RunningTotal
    WHERE RunningTotal.ID = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT recursiveCTE.ID + 1,
        RunningTotal.CumlativeFileSize,
        RunningTotal.FileSize,
        (
            CASE 
                WHEN RunningTotal.FileSize + BinSize > @maxZipSize
                    THEN RunningTotal.FileSize
                ELSE BinSize + RunningTotal.FileSize
                END
            ) AS BinSize,
        (
            CASE 
                WHEN RunningTotal.FileSize + BinSize > @maxZipSize
                    THEN recursiveCTE.BatchNumber + 1
                ELSE recursiveCTE.BatchNumber
                END
            ) AS BatchNumber
    FROM recursiveCTE
    INNER JOIN RunningTotal
        ON recursiveCTE.ID + 1 = RunningTotal.ID
    )
SELECT *
FROM recursiveCTE
```